# schema.org / microdata - Product or Offer?

Tags: microdata, schema.org

I am having trouble using MicroFormats and working out which itemtype to use, either Product or Offer. I have used Offer to add data to the various products that we sell (1 per page). Although this validates properly in the Google Structured Data testing tool it will not show the Price/Rating/InStock in the results. If I use a mixture of Product and Offer then it will although I am not sure this is the correct way to do this ?

Thanks,

Rick

```
<title>My Tent</title>
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
<div itemprop="name" class="product-details-title" id="item_product_prop">My Tent</div>
<div itemprop="description" id="item_product_prop">A Description for MyTent</div>
<meta itemprop="aggregateRating" id="item_product_prop" content="[3 Ratings]">
<div id="item_product_prop" itemprop="price">$13</div>
<div itemprop="availability" id="item_product_prop" content="InStock"></div></div>
</div>
```

http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=uploaded:8004e1c78c1098daa7aa283c26b42939

Comment: You are using [tag:microdata], not [tag:microformats]. Please edit your question (and its tags).

Comment: Edited Title & tags as suggested.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If a product is offered for sale on your website, you actually need both Offer and Product on a product page. An Offer should live within Product.

Google also requires price and priceCurrency (both properties of Offer).

Comment: Does this mean that a product with a line like "Call for pricing" may not use the schema.org "Product"?  (i.e. no 'price' then no 'offer'. No 'offer' then no 'product'.)

Answer (score 7):

Good example is provided at [schema.org/Product](http://schema.org/Product) page. Use it as reference example and you will get what you want.

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <span itemprop="name">Kenmore White 17" Microwave</span>
  <img src="kenmore-microwave-17in.jpg" alt='Kenmore 17" Microwave' />
  <div itemprop="aggregateRating"
    itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
   Rated <span itemprop="ratingValue">3.5</span>/5
   based on <span itemprop="reviewCount">11</span> customer reviews
  </div>

  <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
    <span itemprop="price">$55.00</span>
    <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock" />In stock
  </div>
</div>
```

results in

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you need an extra level in your offer.
If you look at http://www.heppnetz.de/ontologies/goodrelations/goodrelations-UML.png, you see that an offer includes one or more products.