# google rich-snippets won't recognize name

Tags: rich-snippets, google-rich-snippets

Google recognizes all my itemprops except the one for name. But I'm not doing anything different there. Do you have an idea what could be missing?

`<div id="itemAll" itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
<span id='myId' itemprop='name'>Product</span>
</div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing to double quotation marks ""

```
<span id="myId" itemprop="name">Product</span>
```

and linking product names with this schema

```
<a itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" href="/product/url"> Product title</a>
```

Or you can use Googles Microdata markup tool

https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-helper

Comment: Also the solution was to have the name outside of the offer scope but within the product scope: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17722371/schema-org-microdata-product-or-offer